# iOS swift Firestore failed on loading gRPC-C++ Framework

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

When I run my firestore code , beginning it is ok. When it comes to running with simulators or my new phone, it goes to this exception regardless of my firestore version :

Some said that it is related to the pen issues but this is not gonna work.Am I not encouraged to use anonymous login ?

Here is my code :

```
        Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (result , error) in
            guard let authResult = result else {
                return
            }
            let user = authResult.user
            let isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous  // true
            if(isAnonymous){
                let uid = user.uid
                User.shared.userId = uid
                print("user id : \(User.shared.userId)")
                let userRef = db.collection("user").document(User.shared.userId)
                userRef.getDocument { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    if (querySnapshot?.get("progress") == nil) {
                           var  dataDict : Dictionary<String , Any> = [:]
                           dataDict["progress"]  = 0
                           userRef.setData(dataDict)
                        }else{
                            let dict = querySnapshot?.data()
                            let sssresult = dict!.filter{ $0.key == "progress" }.first?.value as? Int ?? 0
                            User.shared.progress = sssresult                        
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

  // CocoaPods: try to load from the gRPC-C++ Framework.
    NSBundle* _Nullable FindGrpcCppFrameworkBundle() {
      return [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"org.cocoapods.grpcpp"];
    }
```